# Symfony2 lost authentication

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm building a website with a simple architecture, using FOSuserBundle in a very basic way:

- a public area, where users may be authenticated
- a protected area, where users have to be authenticated
- a login page

Authentication works fine on public pages.
However, when the user goes to a protected page, authentication is lost (anonymous), and user is redirected to the login page.
Nevertheless, the user is still authenticated for public pages.

Here is the firewall config:

```
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
       pattern:   ^/(login$|register|resetting)
       anonymous: true

    secured_area:
        pattern: ^(/[A-Za-z_]*/[A-Za-z0-9-]*/[A-Za-z0-9-]*/.*)|(/[A-Za-z_]*/NT.*)
        form_login:
            provider:    fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            remember_me: true
            use_referer: true
        remember_me:
            key:         %secret%
        anonymous:       false
        logout:          true

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider:    fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            remember_me: true
            use_referer: true
        remember_me:
            key:         %secret%
        anonymous:       true
        logout:          true
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have 2 firewall You need to ask user to authenticate through each one of them. 
Couldnt You stick to main and require some role to access your secure pages?
you could just add remove secured_area firewall and add for example:

```
access_control:     
    - { path: ^/secured, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working fine. So, this means that firewalls work on their own and do not share authentication credits. Well then, I don't understand why I'm authenticated for the main firewall,as I'm logged through the login firewall...

Comment: Yes correct. Firewalls doesnt share authentication token, so You can be authenticated via one, but via second you are anonymous.